# What happens when you repeated modify data on a synced realm?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Suppose I have a realm synced database with say 100,000 objects.

Such data is repeated changed and written over, let's say for 1,000 times each.

If I have a copy of the database on my device before any of the changes is done.

1a. How many objects are actually transferred onto the device after the 1k changes? This affects the bandwidth usage, as well as the initial update time.

1b. How will the database STORAGE use be affected?

2a. If, after 1k changes, the data ends up the same as initial state, what kind of storage is required on server, and

2b. How much space is likely required on the client?

2c. Is there a way to compact the realm on the server, or on the device?

Answer (score 2):

Realm data synchronization transfers operations (updates) rather than whole records. This means that the amount of data that will be transferred is proportional to the amount of changes being made to a database.

Conversely, the storage used on the clients is just proportional to the number of objects in existence (and not, say, the number of updates each object has received).

For your question (2a), the storage requirement on the server with Realm Object Server 1.x is proportional to the total number of updates in the database. Log compaction is a feature we expect to introduce with Realm Object Server 2.0, which is coming soon.

The actual amount of space required on both server and client depends entirely on which exact changes are being made to the database. For example, adding and changing lots of large binary object will have a much bigger impact on storage requirements than small updates to regular data fields on objects.

As for compacting, Realm has supported database compaction on the client for a while (consult the SDK documentation for your preferred platform on how to do this). On the server, there exists similar features, but we are still in the process of discovering how to best expose this to the developer.

Comment: As per documentation, client side database compaction is only available for standalone realms, not synced realm. Or is this not the case anymore?

Comment: @GordonHo This is still the case.